# How to convert string to json in java where string contains json objects and arrays both

Tags: java, json

Hi am trying to convert string json where string contains json objects and arrays both there is some thing braces or quotes missing I am not getting whats wrong happening

```
     String companyid="14";  
            String userid="1002";       
            String projectid="378";
            String scenarioid="1";      
            String xTable = "[{\"Label\":\"A\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"B\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]";
            String yTable = "[{\"Label\":\"1\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"2\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]";
            String zTable = "[{\"Label\":\"Floor1\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"Floor2\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]"; 

 String grid="{\"grids\":{\"xaxis\":\""+xTable+"},{\"yaxis\":\""+yTable+"},{\"zaxis\":\""+zTable+"}";
        String inJson="{\"grid\":\"" +grid + "\"}" ;
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject(inJson);
        System.out.println(user.getString("grid"));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 80 [character 81 line 1]
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:451)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:231)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:320)
    at JsonExcercise.main(JsonExcercise.java:20)
```

Comment: And "line 1 character 81" does not help to locate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

its an escape sequence Problem below is the

String inJson="{\"grid\":\'" +grid + "\'}" ;

Answer (score 0):

the variable `grid` and `inJson` are the wrong json format, redundant front quotation mark in the variable， and you can validate by the online web tool,the following code is correct

```
 String companyid="14";
    String userid="1002";
    String projectid="378";
    String scenarioid="1";
    String xTable = "[{\"Label\":\"A\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"B\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]";
    String yTable = "[{\"Label\":\"1\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"2\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]";
    String zTable = "[{\"Label\":\"Floor1\",\"Dimension\":\"0\"},{\"Label\":\"Floor2\",\"Dimension\":\"10\"}]";
    String grid="{\"grids\":[{\"xaxis\":"+xTable+"},{\"yaxis\":"+yTable+"},{\"zaxis\":"+zTable+"}]}";
    String inJson="{\"companyid\":\"" +companyid + "\",\"userid\":\"" +userid + "\",\"projectid\":\"" +projectid + "\",\"scenarioid\":" +scenarioid + ",\"grid\":" +grid + "}" ;
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject(inJson);
    System.out.println(user.getString("companyid"));
```

and you could learn the json array and the json object

Comment: System.out.println(user.getString("grid")); is getting error

Comment: you can use the `user.get("grid")` or   the injson is:
String inJson="{\"companyid\":\"" +companyid + "\",\"userid\":\"" +userid + "\",\"projectid\":\"" +projectid + "\",\"scenarioid\":" +scenarioid + ",\"grid\":\'" +grid + "\'}" ;

Answer (score -1):

The error you got sais: org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}'
1st step is to check that the number of '{' and '}' match.
if you look at your code:

```
String grid="{\"grids\":{\"xaxis\":\""+xTable+"},{\"yaxis\":\""+yTable+"},{\"zaxis\":\""+zTable+"}";
```

is not balanced, it is missing a '}'